# How to run the mutex code in c#.net on button click event?

Tags: c#, .net, mutex

This is my code which I had tried to run in my c# .net 3.5 program but I'm getting errors. What am I doing wrong?

> error CS0115: 'Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

This is the code where i got the error:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        this._userConnectionOption = null;
        this._poolGroup = null;
        this.close();
    }
    this.DisposeMe(disposing);
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

The actual coding starts from here:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PU;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // If this program is already running, set focus
            // to that instance and quit.
            if (ProcessUtils.ThisProcessIsAlreadyRunning())
            {
                // "Form1" is the caption (Text property) of the main form.
                ProcessUtils.SetFocusToPreviousInstance("Form1");
            }
            else
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ProcessUtils.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PU
{
    /// Summary description for ProcessUtils.
    public static class ProcessUtils
    {
        private static Mutex mutex = null;

        /// Determine if the current process is already running
        public static bool ThisProcessIsAlreadyRunning()
        {
            // Only want to call this method once, at startup.
            Debug.Assert(mutex == null);

            // createdNew needs to be false in .Net 2.0, otherwise, if another     instance of
            // this program is running, the Mutex constructor will block, and then throw 
            // an exception if the other instance is shut down.
            bool createdNew = false;

            mutex = new Mutex(false, Application.ProductName, out createdNew);

            Debug.Assert(mutex != null);

            return !createdNew;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetLastActivePopup(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool IsWindowEnabled(IntPtr hWnd);

        /// Set focus to the previous instance of the specified program.
        public static void SetFocusToPreviousInstance(string windowCaption)
        {
            // Look for previous instance of this program.
            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, windowCaption);

            // If a previous instance of this program was found...
            if (hWnd != null)
            {
                // Is it displaying a popup window?
                IntPtr hPopupWnd = GetLastActivePopup(hWnd);

                // If so, set focus to the popup window. Otherwise set focus
                // to the program's main window.
                if (hPopupWnd != null && IsWindowEnabled(hPopupWnd))
                {
                    hWnd = hPopupWnd;
                }

                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

                // If program is minimized, restore it.
                if (IsIconic(hWnd))
                {
                    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I'm getting errors" isn't precise. Say exactly *what* errors you're getting.

Comment: Too much code, post the code SNIPPET(S) that are generating errors and the actual errors, please.

Comment: i have gone through the code of mutex.. but it is giving me errors like:-public override void dispose(bool disposing); no suitable method found to dispose.. this is ocuring on initialize component.. so i have commented that portion.. but major error im facing is on the design view part:- The designer cannot process the code at line 26: throw new NotImplementedException(); The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again. i cannot view form.cs[design] plz help me out

Comment: You haven't posted a Dispose method (and again, case *matters* in C# - so post exactly what you've typed, rather than ignoring case). When the error occurs in some code you haven't shown, that's a pretty strong suggestion that we're not going to be able to help much.

Comment: error CS0115: 'Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override 
this is the code where i got the error 
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) { 
if (disposing) { 
this._userConnectionOption = null; 
this._poolGroup = null; this.close(); 
} 
this.DisposeMe(disposing); 
base.Dispose(disposing); 
}

Comment: sir this is the only error im getting;
it is showing me one error
and that is too on Dispose
ths is exactly waht i have coded
i have posted the error no.
and also tell me that how to call that mutex object on button click
what will be the coding for button click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your mutex with `true`as the first param.

And insert

```
if(!createdNew)
    mutex.Close();
```

before

```
return !createdNew;
```

Comment: thanks sir but my error is still not solved
i need to know about the error i got on the:-
error CS0115: 'Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: I guess you derived your form from IDisposable and didn't implement Dispose()

Comment: how to impliment Dispose plz elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

By default, a windows 'Form' (in namespace System.Windows.Forms) implements IDisposable (in namespace System)

But from the error message it looks like your "Form1" does not extend the 'Form' class. Hence in your code the compiler is complaining about the absence of 'over-riddable' method.

Could you please also post your 'Form1' code ?